# JDBC connection to sourceforge's mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sourceforge

How do you specify that the JDBC connection to mysql in the typical line

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql-o.sourceforge.net:4040/o582544_oopp", "user", "pass");
```

I requested the remote access from sourceforge but using the given port 4040 i no able to connect to it.

Here is the error:

```
    Driver Loaded.
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2370)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2154)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at TestMySQL.main(TestMySQL.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
    ... 15 more

Process completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

the URL syntax is given here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

I think you have another issue.

The default port for MySQL is 3306.  I'm not sure where you got that port number, or the username and password you're using, but that message suggests to me that you were able to make the connection but MySQL refused you access.

MySQL GRANTs permissions for access from a particular IP address.  I can't imagine that source forge has asked for your IP address, so I'm guessing that your access should be anonymous and read-only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the stack trace that implies that your request is making it to the remote server, so I think you're having a firewall issue of some sort.  Try using telnet to see if you're making a connection:  `telnet mysql-o.sourceforge.net 4040`  You'll get some text from the server if the network is letting you through.  3306 is the usual port for MySQL so you might want to try that too.  You'll need to solve this part first, then whatever permission issues follow.